# adding path overlay using a timer task caught ConcurrentModificationException on zooming

Tags: java, android

I want to draw straight line path between many  geopoints as the code given ..... but if I try to zoomin the map ConcurrentModificationException occurred, 
plz help me.... i am very new for android.....

```
//this is the methode to draw path
 public void draw_path(View view) {
     if(timer!=null)
         timer.cancel();

      timerpath = new Timer();
      timerpath.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
          int i=0;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();

             if(i<replaydata.length-2){
                 GeoPoint point=new GeoPoint((int) (Float.parseFloat(replaydata[i].split("~")[0]) * 1E6),(int) (Float.parseFloat(replaydata[i].split("~")[1])* 1E6));
                 GeoPoint point2=new GeoPoint((int) (Float.parseFloat(replaydata[i+1].split("~")[0]) * 1E6),(int) (Float.parseFloat(replaydata[i+1].split("~")[1])* 1E6));

                 mapOverlays.add(new PathOverlay(point2, point));
                 mapView.postInvalidate();
                 i=i+1;
             }
             }


        }, 50, 500);

    }
//this is the PathOverlay Class
package com.suneeltectonics.tracking;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.Projection;
public class PathOverlay extends Overlay {
private GeoPoint gp1;
private GeoPoint gp2;

public PathOverlay(GeoPoint gp1, GeoPoint gp2) {
    this.gp1 = gp1;
    this.gp2 = gp2;
}

@Override
public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow,
        long when) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
    if (shadow == false) {

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        Point point = new Point();
        projection.toPixels(gp1, point);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        Point point2 = new Point();
        projection.toPixels(gp2, point2);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(6);
        canvas.drawLine((float) point.x, (float) point.y, (float) point2.x,
                (float) point2.y, paint);
    }
    return super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow, when);
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
}

}
 //this is the crash log
 07-26 17:42:30.850: WARN/dalvikvm(2173): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400207d8)
 07-26 17:42:30.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2173): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 07-26 17:42:30.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2173): java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
07-26 17:42:30.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:573)
 07-26 17:42:30.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at com.google.android.maps.OverlayBundle.draw(OverlayBundle.java:44)
07-26 17:42:30.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onDraw(MapView.java:494)
07-26 17:42:30.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6740)
07-26 17:42:30.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
07-26 17:42:30.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
07-26 17:42:30.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
07-26 17:42:30.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
07-26 17:42:30.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
07-26 17:42:30.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
07-26 17:42:30.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
```

07-26 17:42:30.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
    07-26 17:42:30.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
    07-26 17:42:30.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
    07-26 17:42:30.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
    07-26 17:42:30.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1842)
    07-26 17:42:30.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1407)
    07-26 17:42:30.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1163)
    07-26 17:42:30.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
    07-26 17:42:30.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    07-26 17:42:30.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    07-26 17:42:30.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
    07-26 17:42:30.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    07-26 17:42:30.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    07-26 17:42:30.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:891)
    07-26 17:42:30.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:649)
    07-26 17:42:30.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    07-26 17:42:30.920: WARN/ActivityManager(150):   Force finishing activity       com.suneeltectonics.tracking/.ViewReplay

Comment: if i change the time period to 10000ms then it works fine.....

Comment: i am facing the same problem while updating the marker location......

Answer (score 0):

The exception is getting raised due to manipulation of list items...

It is not because of ondraw method but because you are manipulating entire list in every clock cycle.. that's why when the clock cycle is small you have exception but when it is large you dont get any.

Do not try to repopulate and modify all the time ... 
Method invalidate is there so that it can redraw everything but since you have kept a very small trimmer duration it is getting conflict in the values ...